# Регулярка как найти слова/выражения указанные именно в скобках

Tags: регулярные-выражения, re

Как найти слова/значения указанные в скобках перед ключевым словом from ?

> select distinct rtrim(**model**), rtrim(**Otsek_polog**) from SVODKA_SHASSI where ID_KOL =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если кому то понадобится:

```
"[([](\w+)[)]"gm
```